# ddrescue creates image with no content

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, ddrescue

Whenever i try the following command

```
ddrescue /cygdrive/f /cygdrive/e/stickydump.dd
```

i get the following output:

```
GNU ddrescue 1.25
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
     ipos:    4294 MB, non-trimmed:        0 B,  current rate:       0 B/s
     opos:    4294 MB, non-scraped:        0 B,  average rate:       0 B/s
non-tried:        0 B,  bad-sector:    4294 MB,    error rate:  15131 kB/s
  rescued:        0 B,   bad areas:        1,        run time:      2m 57s
pct rescued:    0.00%, read errors:  8454144,  remaining time:         n/a
                              time since last successful read:         n/a
Finished
```

but the drive I'm trying to dump is not even damaged. I can acess all files just fine with the windows explorer. Do i use the command wrong?

These are my drives:

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
C:/cygwin64    243126352 236915628   6210724  98% /
D:             976629756 967002776   9626980 100% /cygdrive/d
E:             125032444   8377648 116654796   7% /cygdrive/e
F:               3948988    926416   3022572  24% /cygdrive/f
Z:               1555160    136252   1418908   9% /cygdrive/z
```

is it because I'm using cygwin and it's not compatible to windows or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ddrescue (and dd) work on block devices (think disks or partitions) or files.

You are trying to use ddrescue on a directory *where a file system upon a block device is mounted*.

RE Cygwin, perhaps there will be some issue there due to raw block device access?

Say for example you had:

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used    Available  Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      3948988      926416  3022572    24%  /cygdrive/f
```

then ddrescue would be run on /dev/sda1.

Also, to create an image using dd or ddrescue, the raw block device would normally have to be unmounted to prevent change (or mounted read only).